# Could you please explain Replication feature of Redis

Tags: redis

I am very new in REDIS cache implementation.

1. Could you please let me know what is the replication factor means?
2. How it works or What is the impact?
   Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the base of Redis replication (excluding the high availability features provided as an additional layer by Redis Cluster or Redis Sentinel) there is a very simple to use and configure leader follower (master-slave) replication: it allows replica Redis instances to be exact copies of master instances. The replica will automatically reconnect to the master every time the link breaks, and will attempt to be an exact copy of it regardless of what happens to the master.

This system works using three main mechanisms:

1. When a master and a replica instances are well-connected, the master keeps the replica updated by sending a stream of commands to the replica, in order to replicate the effects on the dataset happening in the master side due to: client writes, keys expired or evicted, any other action changing the master dataset.
2. When the link between the master and the replica breaks, for network issues or because a timeout is sensed in the master or the replica, the replica reconnects and attempts to proceed with a partial resynchronization: it means that it will try to just obtain the part of the stream of commands it missed during the disconnection.
3. When a partial resynchronization is not possible, the replica will ask for a full resynchronization. This will involve a more complex process in which the master needs to create a snapshot of all its data, send it to the replica, and then continue sending the stream of commands as the dataset changes.

Redis uses by default asynchronous replication, which being low latency and high performance, is the natural replication mode for the vast majority of Redis use cases.

Synchronous replication of certain data can be requested by the clients using the WAIT command. However WAIT is only able to ensure that there are the specified number of acknowledged copies in the other Redis instances, it does not turn a set of Redis instances into a CP system with strong consistency: acknowledged writes can still be lost during a failover, depending on the exact configuration of the Redis persistence. However with WAIT the probability of losing a write after a failure event is greatly reduced to certain hard to trigger failure modes.